# AJAX request is successful but Datables not populating with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm making a successful AJAX call but the data is still not being filled up with the data.

HTML:

```
<div id="modal"class="modal-body">
  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:vulnDetails()" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="modalButton">Show Vulnerabilities</button><div id="myData">
    <table id="example" class="display" style="display:none"cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ip</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>vulnerability</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
   </table>          
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function vulnDetails(){
    $('#example').show();
   $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: '/vulnDetails',
                 data: function ( d ) {
                    return JSON.stringify(data2)},
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 dataSrc: ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "ip" },
            { "data": "desciption" },
            { "data": "vulnerability" },
        ]
    } );
}
```

The request returns a 200 code and the table is created, but it just says that there is no data available.

Does anybody have any ideas?

JSON:

```
 [{'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'vulnerability': 118860, 'description': 'The credentials supplied for the snmp scanning feature encountered an error.'}, {'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'vulnerability': 127166, 'description': 'Samba winbind_name_list_to_sid_string_list security bypass'}, {'ip': u'1.1.1.1', 'vulnerability': 132630, 'description': 'Samba SAMR information disclosure'}, {'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'vulnerability': 132630, 'description': 'Samba SAMR information disclosure'}]
```

Comment: does data structure match expected structure per plugin docs?

Comment: Yes it does, it's a flat array which i cross checked with the datatables examples. I updated the OP with it regardless.

Comment: Your data doesn't parse as valid json according to [jsonlint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/)...

Comment: You have a typo in the third object of your array, where `{'ip': u'1.1.1.1'` the `u` can't be there.

Comment: That JSON was copied from the backend, it's just a unicode string. It makes no difference, I had just removed it manually for this post missed that one.  The JSON is valid I promise lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove empty function dataSrc

Comment: That is needed (because i'm requesting a flat array) otherwise I get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Removed dataType: "json",

```
function vulnDetails(){
    $('#example').show();
   $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: '/vulnDetails',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataSrc: ''
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "ip" },
            { "data": "desciption" },
            { "data": "vulnerability" },
        ]
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the data structure should be something like

```
  {
  "data": [{'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'vulnerability': 118860, 'description': 'The credentials     supplied for the snmp scanning feature encountered an error.'}, {'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'vulnerability': 127166, 'description': 'Samba winbind_name_list_to_sid_string_list security bypass'}, {'ip': u'1.1.1.1', 'vulnerability': 132630, 'description': 'Samba SAMR information disclosure'}, {'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'vulnerability': 132630, 'description': 'Samba SAMR information disclosure'}]
  }
```

If you choose this route according to [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html).  You should have included your back-end function. There your data should be the value inside an array with data as key for example in php

```
    $data_to_return=array('data'=>$your_data);
    echo $data_to_return;
```

Cheers

This is what should be done for your code to work. corrections

1) JSon array is invalid this is a typical valid JSon object

```
            [
               {
                "ip": "1.1.1.1", 
                "vulnerability": "118860", 
                "description": "The credentials supplied for the snmp  scanning feature encountered an error."
                }, 
               {
               "ip": "1.1.1.1", 
               "vulnerability": "127166", 
               "description": "Samba winbind_name_list_to_sid_string_list security bypass"
               },
              {
             "ip": "1.1.1.1", 
             "vulnerability": "132630", 
             "description": "Samba SAMR information disclosure"
              }, 
             {
              "ip": "1.1.1.1",
               "vulnerability": "132630",
               "description": "Samba SAMR information disclosure"
              }
            ]
```

Sorry I had overlooked this before

2)Correct the spelling of description in

```
         { "data": "desciption" },
```

change to

```
         { "data": "description" },
```

and off you go. Cheers

Comment: It doesn't have to have an initial key. Look at this: https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html

Comment: But I said if you choose this route. Anyway let me modify the answer

Comment: I have added a working response. I have tried this out and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function vulnDetails(){
    $('#example').show();
   $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: '/vulnDetails',
                 "dataSrc": function(data){ return data.data; },
                 "data": function(data){
                // Send data as json for POST.
                return JSON.stringify(data); 
                }
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 "processData": true,
                 "async": true,
                  "accepts": {
                      json: "application/json, text/javascript"
                   }
                        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "ip" },
            { "data": "desciption" },
            { "data": "vulnerability" },
        ]
    } );
}
```